# Display The Result Of a SQL Query Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, cordova

I've been reading a tutorial called [Adding SQL Database support to your iPhone App](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494756/Adding-SQL-Database-support-to-your-iPhone-App)(I use PhoneGap because I won't get on Objective-C), I've done that all, but now when I tried to display the result(`celebsDataHandler`) like this it shows nothing:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="db.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  document.write(celebsDataHandler);
</script>
```

What should I do to correct this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`celebsDataHandler` appears to be a function, based on what the tutorial says. You can't `document.write` a function.

Have you tried using a more versatile command like `console.log` to see what the value of `celebsDataHandler` is?

Or, you may wish to change the last line of the function from

```
  alert(html);
```

to

```
  return html;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to have some part of your document set up to handle showing the celebrities, for this example. Make sure you have a DOM element in your HTML page that has an ID that you can reference, for example:

```
<div id="myCelebs"></div>
```

Next, change the last line of the `celebsDataHandler` function to:

```
document.getElementById('myCelebs').innerHTML = html;
```

Finally, in your inline script, change your `document.write` call to:

```
loadCelebs();
```

To recap what is going on:

- The `loadCelebs` function contains the SQLite code that queries the database and retrieves your data. It references a **callback function** (in this case named `celebsDataHandler`) that is invoked once the data is ready to be parsed.
- The `celebsDataHandler` callback function iterates over results and compiles celebrity data into HTML - which it then injects into the "myCelebs" DOM element.

Hope that helps.